# In proof that smooth point is regular ( First quetion, Gortz's Algebraic Geometry )

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Lemma 6.26 and trying to prove some statement in it.

First I propose a question. Let $R:=k[T_1, \dots,T_n]$ be a polynomial ring with closed point $y\in \operatorname{Spec}R$ so that $\mathfrak{p}_y$ is the maximal ideal in $R$. Let $\mathfrak{m}_y$ be the maximal ideal of the local ring $R_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ ; i.e., $\mathfrak{m}_y := \mathfrak{p}_y R_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$. Let $f_1, \dots f_r$ be elements of $\mathfrak{p}_y \subseteq R$ and $a_1, \dots a_r $ be elements of $k$. Consider its images $f_1/1 , \dots , f_r/1 \in \mathfrak{m}_y $.

**Q.** Then, my question is, if $a_1 \cdot \frac{f_1}{1} + \cdots + a_r \cdot \frac{f_r}{1} = \frac{a_1 f_1 + \cdots + a_r f_r}{1} \in \mathfrak{m}_y^2 $ ,  then $\Sigma_{i} a_i \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j} \in \mathfrak{p}_y$ for all $j$ ? I am trying to prove this by brutal force and can't prove yet.

This question originates from following proof ( Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book Lemma 6.26 )

> Lemma 6.26. Let $k$ be a field, and $X$ a $k$-scheme, locally of finite type. Let $x\in X$ be a point such that $X$ is smooth at $x$ of relative dimension $d$ over $k$. Then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular of dimension $\le d$. If $x$ is closed, then $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x}=d$.

Here the smoothness is defined as

[image]

( Note the underlined statement. )

*Proof of the Lemma 6.26.* Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $U$ is smooth over $k$. As the closed points of $X$ are very dense, there exists a closed point $x'$ of $X$ with $x'\in U \cap \overline{\{x\}}$. If we have shown that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x'}$ is regular, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, being a localization of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x'}$, is also regular by Proposition $B.77 (1)$ and $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \le \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x'}$. Thus we may assume that $x$ is a closed point.

We may accept this argument. If needed, I will upload details.

( Continuing proof ) We embed a neighborhood of $x$ into an affine space as in the definition of smoothness and denote $y\in \mathbb{A}^{n}_k$ the image of $x$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n}_k ,y} / ( f_1, \dots , f_{n-d})$, with polynomials $f_j \in k[T_1,\dots, T_n]$ such that the matrix $((\partial f_i / \partial T_j )(y))_{i,j}$ has rank $n-d$. I think that more correct notation is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n}_k ,y}/(\frac{f_1}{1} , \dots , \frac{f_{n-d}}{1})$, where $\frac{f_i}{1} $ is the image of $f_i$ in $k[T_1,\dots T_n]_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$. **By Example 6.5 this means that the images of $f_1 ,\dots , f_{n-d}$ in $(T_y \mathbb{A}^{n}_k )^{*} = \mathfrak{m}_y/\mathfrak{m}_y^2$ are linearly independent ( where $\mathfrak{m}_y$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n}_k,y}$)**.
Here the Example 6.5 is,

[image]

( Continuing proof ) **In fact, if $\kappa(y) = k$, then this follows immediately.** The general case is reduced to this case as follows. ( Next proof is omitted ). As $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n}_k ,y}$ is regular, Proposition $B.77 (3)$ implies that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular of dimension $d$. **QED.**

I am trying to understand the bold statement. Let $r:=n-d$. We need to show that $\frac{f_1}{1} + \mathfrak{m}_y^2 , \dots , \frac{f_{r}}{1} + \mathfrak{m}_y^2$ is linearly independent over $\kappa(y) = k$. So let $a_1, \dots , a_r \in k$ such that $a_1 ( f_1/1 + \mathfrak{m}_y^2 ) + \cdots + a_r ( f_r/1 + \mathfrak{m}_y^2)=0$ so that $\frac{a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_rf_r}{1}\in \mathfrak{m}_y^2$. If our above question is true, then $\Sigma_i a_i \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j} \in \mathfrak{p}_y$ for all $j$. It means that the matrix multiplication

$$ (a_1,\dots , a_r) ( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j} + \mathfrak{p}_y )_{1 \le i \le r, 1 \le j \le n } =0 \tag{1}$$

is zero. But note that ( from the underlined remark in the definition of smoothness (above image ) ) $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j}(y)$ is the image of $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n}_k,y}/\mathfrak{m}_y \cong k[T_1,\dots , T_n] /\mathfrak{p}_y$ ( $\because$ $\mathfrak{p}_y$ is maximal ) so that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j}(y) = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j} + \mathfrak{p}_y$. So from the $(1)$,

$$ (a_1, \dots , a_r) J_{f_1, \dots , f_r}(y) =0. \tag{2} $$

But since $ J_{f_1, \dots , f_r}(y)$ ( the jacobian ) has rank $r=n-d$, by taking transpose, we have that $(a_1 , \dots, a_r) =0$ and we are done. Correct argument? If so, my first question is true? Or is there any other route to show the bold statement more simply , for example by refering the above Example 6.5.?

P.s. Furthur question : In the proof of the Lemma 6.26, to show the linear independence, Gortz reduced the general case ( that possibly $k \neq \kappa(y)$ ) to the case $\kappa(y) =k$, which is proven. I omitted such proof ( If needed, I will upload ) Then my question is, other than such reduction mechanism, can we try to prove general case by imitating the above argument?

Thanks for reading. Can anyone help?

Comment: Downvoting a question with context and explanation/effort like this is not reasonable. I've had a conversation like this before with questions from this user but if someone is badly confused, downvoting isn't going to make them any less confused! What are we, the volunteers, even doing here if that's our attitude? If it's not worth your time consider taking no action at all, no reason to actively downvote

Comment: Thanks. Yes, and I feel like certain people who don't like me are constantly voting against it. I want to be friendly with everyone, but I'd like to have a system to prevent people ( if they exist ) from continuously downvoting by targeting specific people :) Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notation, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n,y}/(f_1,...,f_{n-d})$ is an abbreviation so yes, if you write things in coordinate like $k[x_1,...,x_n]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ then we should write $f_1/1,...,f_{n-d}/1$ instead.

For the bold statement, note that in example 6.5, authors are assuming that the point $x$ is a $k$-point, that is $\kappa(x)=k$. This simply makes it possible to obtain a concrete description of the tangent space. The proof of **Lemma 6.26** continues by trying to obtain information from this case through base change.

For your first concern, then the answer is yes as well, the derivative $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ sends $\mathfrak{m}^2$ to $\mathfrak{m}$, this should be obvious because $D(fg) = fD(g) + gD(f)$.

Comment: Thank you. And how the description of the tangent space in the Example 6.5 leads to the linear independence ?

Comment: @Plantation, I think you reasoning is fine

Comment: O.K. Thank you ! :)

Comment: For the first concern in your answer, let's substitute our $\mathfrak{m}_y$ to the $\mathfrak{m}$. Then each element of $\mathfrak{m}_y$ is of the form $b/s$, where $b \in \mathfrak{p}_y$ and $s\in R - \mathfrak{p}_y$. Then how the derivative $D:=\frac{\partial}{\partial T_j}$ of $b/s$ is defined? It seems that it needs to introduction of formal partial derivative of rational polynomial ( and such derivative satisfies the product rule? ) and I think that it is first time to come across such concept.

Comment: If we can show $\frac{\partial}{\partial T_j}((a_1 f_1 + \cdots + a_r f_r)/1 ) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial T_j} ( a_1 f_1 + \cdots + a_r f_r )) /1$, then we can answer to the first question affirmatively. How do you think about this?

Comment: Well, if you know how to take the derivative of functions $f(x)/g(x)$, then it should be the same in this case.

Comment: O.K. Thank you :)

Comment: Alexey Do, And, I posed a question which aims to show the reductibility of the general case for the linear independence to the case that $k= \kappa(y)$. : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874250/understanding-proof-that-smooth-point-is-regular-second-quetion-gortzs-algeb . Perhaps, if you have time, can you review it?